# Combinations for 15 equivalent objects among 3 places.

Tags: combinatorics

> Have 15 computers (they're all the same) that must be distributed to 3
>   offices.
>
> If the first office must have, **at most**, 4 computers, how many ways
>   are there to distribute them?

Am I right in answering

$$\sum_{i = 0}^{4}(C(15,i) * C(15 - i + 1, 1))$$

?

It is my understanding that when a question says something like "at most", you have to make a sum. However I am unsure about the product I have in there - should that be a product or yet another addition?

Comment: Is it ok if an office receives no computers?

Comment: @Awesome: Yeah, it's ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First ignore the restriction concerning the first office.  The number of ways to distribute the $15$ identical computers is $C(17,2)$.

Now any distribution in which the first office gets $5$ computers or more should not have been included.  To count these distributions, put $5$ computers into the first office, then decide how to distribute the remaining $10$.  There are $C(12,2)$ ways to do this.

So the number of allowable distributions is $C(17,2)-C(12,2)$.

**Comment**.  We are looking for the number of distributions in which the first office receives $0$ computers, **or** $1$ computer, **or**. . . **or** $4$ computers, and this can indeed be done by a sum.  If the first office receives $0$ computers then we have to distribute $15$ among $2$ offices, and there are $C(16,1)$ ways of doing this.  Using similar ideas for the other cases, we get
$$\sum_{k=0}^4 C(15-k+1,1)$$
possibilities.  However in this case, I think you will agree that the other method is simpler.

Comment: Shouldn't C(14,2) be C(12,2)?

Comment: @Awesome, yes, and the $12$ should have been $10$.  Both fixed.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Number of ways will be coefficient of $x^{15}$ in

$$f(x)=(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4)(1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^{15})^2=(1-x^5)(1-x^{16})^2(1-x)^{-3}=(1-x^5-2x^{16}+2x^{21}
+x^{32}-x^{37})(1+\binom{3}{1}x+\binom{4}{2}x^2+\cdots)$$

Thus number of ways is $\binom{17}{2}-\binom{12}{2}=70$

Comment: Typo: The coefficient of $x^{15}$ is $\binom{\color{green}{17}}{2}$ and  $x^{10}$ is $\binom{\color{green}{12}}{2}$

Comment: @Anant-Corrected. Thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer seems to be mixing computations where the computers are distinguishable, and computations where the computers are indistinguishable.  In fact the problem specifies every computer is the same, so refer to David's answer for the correct solution.

If the computers *were* distinguishable, the start of your answer would be right.  Then the entire formula would be
$$
\sum_{i = 0}^{4}(C(15,i) \left[ \sum_{j=0}^{15-i} C(15 - i, j) \right]
= \sum_{i=0}^4 C(15,i) 2^{15-i}.
$$